# How to simplify this JavaScript code through a "for" loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

How can I simplify this JavaScript code through a “for” loop so that it is one loop?

```
        if (j.di_1[0] == 1) {
          q("di1_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di1_3").className = "fg";
          q("di1_1").className = "wg"
        } else {
          q("di1_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di1_3").className = "fr";
          q("di1_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di1_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_1[1]);
        if (j.di_2[0] == 1) {
          q("di2_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di2_3").className = "fg";
          q("di2_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_2[0] == 0) {
          q("di2_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di2_3").className = "fr";
          q("di2_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di2_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_2[1]);
        if (j.di_3[0] == 1) {
          q("di3_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di3_3").className = "fg";
          q("di3_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_3[0] == 0) {
          q("di3_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di3_3").className = "fr";
          q("di3_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di3_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_3[1]);
        if (j.di_4[0] == 1) {
          q("di4_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di4_3").className = "fg";
          q("di4_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_4[0] == 0) {
          q("di4_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di4_3").className = "fr";
          q("di4_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di4_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_4[1]);
        if (j.di_5[0] == 1) {
          q("di5_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di5_3").className = "fg";
          q("di5_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_5[0] == 0) {
          q("di5_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di5_3").className = "fr";
          q("di5_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di5_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_5[1]);
        if (j.di_6[0] == 1) {
          q("di6_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di6_3").className = "fg";
          q("di6_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_6[0] == 0) {
          q("di6_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di6_3").className = "fr";
          q("di6_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di6_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_6[1]);
        if (j.di_7[0] == 1) {
          q("di7_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di7_3").className = "fg";
          q("di7_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_7[0] == 0) {
          q("di7_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di7_3").className = "fr";
          q("di7_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di7_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_7[1]);
        if (j.di_8[0] == 1) {
          q("di8_3").innerHTML = h;
          q("di8_3").className = "fg";
          q("di8_1").className = "wg"
        } else if (j.di_8[0] == 0) {
          q("di8_3").innerHTML = l;
          q("di8_3").className = "fr";
          q("di8_1").className = "wr"
        }
        q("di8_4").innerHTML = sectoday(j.di_8[1]);
```

Wrote straight forward code to display the output on the page. It performs its function as it should and very quickly, but I understand with all my heart that it shouldn’t be this way.

Unfortunately, I don’t have enough knowledge to cope with this task myself.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. Your question currently is too broad and misses details and clarity in the form of context to the task and issue. E.g. What is `q`? what is `sectoday`? what is `j`? If work with arrays, node list, HTML Collection Objects or similar than post them here too for context.

Comment: There's probably a way to hack some strings together, as the answer provided by Gag below shows, however I would still suggest this is a terrible approach. A better idea would be to refactor the data structure to avoid having to do that at all. Exactly how you do that would depend on many factors, of which there's not enough information in the question to give you a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that applies that behaviour to each element like this and then just run a loop to call this function as many times as needed. Feel free to change the loop according to your needs.

I dont have your full code or relevant data so I can't really make a working example, HTML unknown and also the values of `j`, `h` or `l`.

```js
function updateElementData(elementIndex, j) {
  const index = elementIndex.toString();
  const commonClassName = "wr";
  const positiveClassName = "wg";
  const negativeClassName = "fr";
  const valueToDisplay = j[`di_${index}`][0] === 1 ? h : l;

  q(`di${index}_3`).innerHTML = valueToDisplay;
  q(`di${index}_3`).className = j[`di_${index}`][0] === 1 ? positiveClassName : negativeClassName;
  q(`di${index}_1`).className = j[`di_${index}`][0] === 1 ? positiveClassName : commonClassName;
  q(`di${index}_4`).innerHTML = sectoday(j[`di_${index}`][1]);
}

for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
    updateElementData(i, j);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    const di = j[`di_${i}`];
    if (di[0] == 1) {
        q(`di${i}_3`).innerHTML = h;
        q(`di${i}_3`).className = "fg";
        q(`di${i}_1`).className = "wg";
    } else if (di[0] == 0) {
        q(`di${i}_3`).innerHTML = l;
        q(`di${i}_3`).className = "fr";
        q(`di${i}_1`).className = "wr";
    }
    q(`di${i}_4`).innerHTML = sectoday(di[1]);
}
```

Comment: Shorter version -

for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    const value = j[`di_${i}`][0]
    q(`di${i}_3`).innerHTML = value === 1 ? h : l;
    q(`di${i}_3`).className = value === 1 ? "fg" : "fr";
    q(`di${i}_1`).className = value === 1 ? "wg" : "wr";
    q(`di${i}_4`).innerHTML = sectoday(j[`di_${i}`][1]);
}

Comment: @AmitGurbani yes it is shorter. Thanks